# Apply signTab for > 25mb documents using DocuSign REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

Using REST API v2. (existing code)(not v2.1)

Adding multiple documents to an envelope.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/

Initial draft envelope contains recipients and signHere tab/signedDate tab (not using templates) for autoPlace.

When the document base64 payload exceeds 25mb (DocuSign API limit), additional documents are added  via this to the draft envelope.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/updatelist/

At the end, updating envelope status to 'Sent'.
This resulted in the 1st API call's documents to show sign tags, but subsequent documents added by envelopedocuments/updatelist do not auto render sign tags.

We are using the default AnchorScope of Envelope.

I tried adding *advanced_update=true* parameter to envelope update.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/
This made sign tags to not appear in any document.

*When set to true, allows the caller to update recipients, tabs, custom fields, notification, email settings and other envelope attributes.*

Next I re-applied the recipients and signTab information in the envelope update API call.
This resulted in infinite loop when signing (cannot complete the document).

Next I took out the recipients and signTab from the initial envelope create API call so only the final envelope update API call contains the recipients and signTab.  (still using *advanced_update=true*)

This got to the state that I was looking for, with all the documents having sign tags.

Is this the proper order to specify recipients/signTabs when dealing with multiple API call when combined documents exceed the 25mb limit?

Comment: Is it possible the tab population scope is set to document and not to envelope? that can only be changed by contacting DocuSign Support. This scope determine when using anchor strings if all documents are searched (envelope level) or document by document (document level)

Comment: I asked and nobody has changed the default scope.   We weren't able to see the setting in DocuSign admin.   As an update, we thought the issue was resolved, but the latest change also produced the infinite signing behavior (signed till the end, it ends on the top document to be signed again).

Comment: Can you share your code in here?

Comment: Also, why not use API V2.1?

Comment: What do you mean by repeat signing? do you see each tab (signing element) duplicated?

Comment: Using Postman, Add Documents payload had a duplicate DocumentId indicated by the response.  This was causing duplicate sets of sign tab to be created (but limited to 2 sets).  Setting an unique DocumentId fixed the issue submitted from Postman.

Comment: OK, so do you still have an issue?

Comment: Confirmed this is working now.   (Not setting recipient Sign tab in initial envelop but set it in the final updateEnvelope).